# USB Device Power Usage

Tags: power-management, battery, thinkpad, powertop, tlp

I've been searching and messing around with powertop, tlp, and general power settings for a few days now and just can't seem to get rid of this ridiculous power drainage from a usb device. (Color sensor by Pantone - aka "X-Rite")

[image: Powertop Overview]

All tunables are set to 'Good'.

My laptop is a ThinkPad W541 and I am running Ubuntu 16.04

Any help/tips would be greatly appreciated for power saving even if unrelated from the usb device, but the usb is my main concern.

Comment: Maybe the usb device(color sensor by Pantone - aka "X-Rite") needs that much power. Would it be possible to feed it with power separately? It could be done directly, if there is a connector for it, or indirectly via a USB hub with separate power supply.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable USB autosuspend mode for the Bluetooth device.

I suggest you [install TLP](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html) to achieve this. TLP's default configuration will enable autosuspend for all USB devices except (externally attached) mice and keyboards.

If you don't use Bluetooth at all, you may even disable it at boot time by enabling the following line in TLP's [configuration](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html#radios)

Open terminal and run

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/tlp
```

Uncomment (remove `#` from the start of the line) this line in the tlp file

```
DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_STARTUP="bluetooth"
```

Save the file and exit, and reboot to test the result.

Comment: The question said they are using TLP already. How can you tell this is the solution from their output & description?